# Лямбды в Java 8, что лучше использовать - Function.identity() или t->t?

Tags: java, java-8, lambda, java-faq

Вопрос по использованию `Function.identity()` метода.

Допустим, есть следующий код:

```
Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c")
          .stream()
          .map(Function.identity()) // <- Этот кусок
          .map(str -> str)          // <- равен этому.
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                       Function.identity(), // <-- А этот
                       str -> str));        // <-- равен этому.
```

Должен ли я использовать `Function.identity()` вместо `str->str`(или наоборот)? Я думаю, что второй вариант более читабелен и понимаем(допустим, если новый человек не знает что делает `identity`). Но есть ли «реальная» причина, из-за которой следует отдать предпочтение одному из способов?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032827/java-8-lambdas-function-identity-or-t-t

Comment: И про `collect` кто-то может не знать, и про `map`, если этот кто-то знаком с функциональным программированием меньше недели. Если писать код, который смогут прочитать даже такие специалисты, увы, только они этот код и станут читать.

Comment: @extrn невозможно помнить все API и методы библиотеки(любой). `identity()` - не такой важный метод, чтобы всегда помнить что он делает.

Comment: Термин [Identity function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_function) известен далеко за пределами `java API`, и реализации такой функции присутствуют во многих функциональных языках: [Common Lisp](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/iiip/doc/CommonLISP/HyperSpec/Body/fun_identity.html), [Haskell](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:id), [F#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.id%5B%27t%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D), [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#identity[A](x:A):A) и т.д.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Первоначально кажется, что у этих двух способов нет отличия, ведь реализация `identity()` такова:

```
static <T> Function<T, T> identity() {
    return t -> t;
}
```

Однако `Function.identity()` всегда будет возвращать один и тот же экземпляр([обоснование этого решения](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032827/java-8-lambdas-function-identity-or-t-t#comment49724366_28033143)), в то время как `t -> t` не только будет создавать новый экземпляр, но даже будет иметь отдельный класс реализации. Для более подробной информации смотрите [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27524543/2711488).

Причина в том, что компилятор генерирует синтетический метод, содержащий тело лямбда выражений(случае `t -> t` это будет `return t;`) и указывает среде выполнения создать реализацию функционального интерфейса, вызывающего этот метод.

Поэтому использование `Function.identity()` вместо `t -> t`может сэкономить немного памяти, но совсем небольшое количество, поэтому это не должно влиять на ваше решение, если вы считаете, что `t -> t` более читабельно, чем `Function.identity()`.

Также в некоторых методах нельзя вызвать `Function.identity()`. 
Допустим, есть такой список:

```
List<Integer> list ... 
...
```

Код ниже отлично скомпилируется:

```
int[] arrayOK = list.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
```

Но если попытаться скомпилировать следующий код, то будет ошибка компиляции:

```
int[] arrayProblem = list.stream().mapToInt(Function.identity()).toArray();
```

Она произойдет из-за того что `mapToInt` ожидает `ToIntFunction`, которая не связана с `Function`. Также у `ToIntFunction` нет метода `identity()`.

Comment: `в то время как t -> t **каждый раз** не только будет создавать новый экземпляр, но даже будет иметь отдельный класс реализации` - нет в оригинале фразы про "каждый раз", там даже есть [ссылка на связанный ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27524445/does-a-lambda-expression-create-an-object-on-the-heap-every-time-its-executed/27524543#27524543), где сказано, что на лямбда выражение в котором нет захвата внешних значений будет создан синглтон, но при этом два идентичных лямбда выражения в разных местах породят два синглтона.

Comment: **Однако Function.identity() всегда будет возвращать один и тот же экземпляр** Так внутри него ведь итак имеется лямбда, соответственно, эта функция также будет возвращать каждый раз новый объект?

Comment: @Dred что? Нет, будет все тот же объект, как и `t -> t`